# Is blood necessary to perform the summoning jutsu?

Tags: naruto

I always thought that blood is necessary to perform the summoning jutsu. However, I saw the second Mizukage and Madara performing it while being [Edo Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation), so is it really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

[Summoning Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique)

> ... and seemingly did not require a blood offering when performing this technique.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, yes.

Why do you need blood?

Well [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/27640/20270) answer states that:

> **the blood serves as a means of identifying the summoner for the summoned and also acts as a price (sacrifice) for calling them.**

So you **need** a "sacrifice" (in this case blood) to summon.

But, according to the [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique), Nagato can summon without this sacrifice:

> While most summoners have only been shown capable of summoning one type of creature, **Nagato (through the Animal Path) was able to summon several different animals and even people, and seemingly did not require a blood offering when performing this technique**.

I suppose since the [Animal Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Path) was a dead person, then it didn't need blood. Same goes for the Second Mizukage and Madara.

- Reanimations can't bleed because

> Any damage they receive will regenerate in time and, assuming the damage is not too debilitating, they can continue attacking even before their body recovers.
>   [image]
>   - [wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation)